# Jquery UI Dialog: close from inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to close jQuery UI Dialog from within externally loaded file, which contain a link, which clicked should close the dial.

The "base" file contains the following:

```
<div id="dialog-operations"><div id="dialog-content"></div></div>
<a href="#" id="search-client-button">Search</a>
```

And the script:

```
$("#dialog-operations").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Search",
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    modal: true,
    position: { my: "center center", at: "center center" },
    open:  function(event, ui) {
        $('#dialog-content').load('myFile.html');
    },
    close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
});

$("#search-client-button").click(function() {
    $("#dialog-operations").dialog("open");
});
```

Dynamically loaded `myFile.html` performs the search via Ajax and shows some links that perform some actions and at the end should close the Dialog (in the following example I just try to close the Dialog on Ajax complete):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "search.php",
    data: $("#search-user-form").serialize(),
    type: "GET",
    context: this
}).done(function(data) {
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close'); // not working
        $("#dialog-operations").dialog( "close" ); // not working
        $(this).dialog("close"); // not working
        this.close(); // not working
        $(this).dialog().dialog("close") // not working
});
```

The Dialog doesn't close, and in FireBug console I receive errors on undefined methods, or the following one:

```
Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to close the Dialog from within a file loaded with Ajax? I'm using jQuery 1.11.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.4.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions!

**EDIT**

After @Justin's help and many deliberations this is the code I finally end up with. The important info is: first load the file, and then define the Dialog!

```
$("#dialog-content").load('myFile.html', function(){
    $("#dialog-operations").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Search",
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "center center", at: "center center" }
    });

    $("#search-client-button").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-operations").dialog("open");
    });

});
```

And in the included file (the important fragment only):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "search.php",
    data: $("#search-user-form").serialize(),
    type: "GET",
    context: this
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#dialog-operations").dialog("close");
});
```

Unfortunately this approach breaks the separation (the included file makes reference to container defined in parent file), so probably I'll just cease the idea of including the Dialog content from a different file. But that's a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the **context** option in your ajax config or try changing the context option to a **DOM element** instead of **this**.

**EDIT**

I think I know now where you went wrong. It may be because the **$.ajax function** has already been executed by javascript before your load function has first finished it's own ajax request. Try running your load function and then supply to it's 2nd parameter a callback function that creates the dialog and other stuffs. I removed the open option

```
open:  function(event, ui) {
    $('#dialog-content').load('myFile.html');
}
```

in your dialog initialization.

```
$('#dialog-content').load('myFile.html', function(){
    $("#dialog-operations").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Search",
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "center center", at: "center center" },
        close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    });

    $("#search-client-button").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-operations").dialog("open");
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        data: $("#search-user-form").serialize(),
        type: "GET",
        context: this
    }).done(function(data) {
        $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close'); // TEST
        $("#dialog-operations").dialog( "close" ); // TEST
        $(this).dialog("close"); // TEST
        this.close(); // TEST
        $(this).dialog().dialog("close") // TEST
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. After some more testing I realized that it's not the ajax problem. I did the following test **on the same page** that opens the Dialog: `$("#search-client-button").click(function() {$("#dialog-operations").dialog("open"); alert('test'); $("#dialog-operations").dialog("close");});` and received the same error in FireBug: `Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`. Looks like loading external file via `.load()` method causes Dialog to loose its context?

Comment: Just confirmed that: changing this part of Dialog: `open:  function(event, ui) {$('#dialog-content').load(url)}` with that one: `$('#dialog-content').html('<div>Test content</div>');` makes that Dialog opens and closes as expected. Still do not know why it does lose its context?

Comment: Justin, that was exactly the problem! First load the external file, and then define Dialog, not the opposite. I'll edit my question to show what I finally end with. Thank you very much for your help!